What will happen if you press all the keys of a keyboard at once
What happens when all keys on a keyboard are pressed simultaneously? How do hardware limitations like key rollover and ghosting affect the input registered by the computer, given that the operating system is Windows 10 and the keyboard is connected via USB (wireless)?

This question is off-topic here.

A USB keyboard will send a sequence of “key pressed” and “key released” events. These events don’t report the letters printed on the key, but the physical keys. In other words if you type blind and we swap your French keyboard for an Italian one, the same keys are reported. A USB keyboard will be clever enough to report these events in matching pairs interspersed as you presses them (for example press key 23, press key 34, release key 34, release key 23).
If many keys are pressed depending on the quality of the keyboard multiple keys may be combined; this will not produce results that shouldn’t be produced.
It is then up to the OS to figure out the physical layout of your keyboard, find out which keys are shift, command, control etc. and which letters have been pressed. That can be complicated.
